# How to clear rabbitmq statistic graphs

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

Am using RabbitMQ for messaging queue and using the statistic graphs provided in the management portal.

I want clear the graphs in between my tests, but don't know how to do it. I did try by clearing rabbitmq logs but no luck!